# Highlighting the lines between brackets that the cursor is in

Tags: c++, vim, terminal

How would I make VIM *automatically* highlight the lines (as I'm typing) between the closest opening bracket before the cursor and the closest matching closing bracket after the cursor?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly `vi{` should work when standing on or within the brackets (use `va{` to include the brackets.

Comment: Or on one of the brackets. And here is the mandatory mention of `:help motion.txt`.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot that - added clarification.

Comment: Also note `iB` is the same as `i{`. The `B` stands for `Block`.

Comment: @fileunderwater

This was kind-of what I was looking for. I want it to do that automatically so I don't have to do it while I'm typing. I was also thinking that changing the background slightly rather than highlighting would work a it better. I think it would help me focus better on the block that I'm editing.

Comment: Sorry cannot help you there. Maybe *BlockHL* could be interesting to check out: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=104